# Iterate over a subset of a ListMultiMap

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, guava, multimap

I've got a Multimap that was originally created with the following statement:

`ListMultimap<String, MyCustomObject> ids = MultimapBuilder.treeKeys().arrayListValues().build();`

I'd like to be able to provide an offset and a limit so that I can turn my multimap into a smaller multimap that holds only keys between the 5th and 10th element of the original multimap (along with their corresponding values). The original `Multimap` may have a huge number of keys, so I don't want to iterate through the keys and call ids.get(key) if I can avoid it because it might be slow. Is there a good way of doing this? It's ok if your solution contains `ids.get(key)`, I just prefer solutions that don't do that if that's even possible.

Comment: I ca`t understandthis: The original Multimap may have a huge number of keys, so I don't want to iterate through the keys and call ids.get(key) if I can avoid it because it might be slow. It does not matter how much element is in your multi hashmap it depends on how much elements you want to get !

Comment: There probably won't be any solution that doesn't iterate through some of the keys, but you can have a solution that only iterates through 10 of the keys.

Comment: That's acceptable

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the `ListMultiMap` from guava, unfortunately you don't have many options, but I can think in somes that could help. Since the `ListMultiMap` doesn't implements `List` or `Map` you will need get the entries and transform into a list, list/arrays have O(1) time operation in addition so, calling a `List list = new ArrayList(ids.entries())` will cost nothing, from here you can get a subset of the list like you said with `List smallList = list.subList(5, 11)` other O(1) operation, since List uses arrays, it will don't need iterate to reach these elements to create a new list, just pick elements between the positions.